# font.TintAndShade cannot change brightness of the text

Tags: excel, text, fonts, brightness, vba

I select a text and change its color and it tells me this

```
Range("A7").Select
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .TintAndShade = -1
End With
```

But when I run this code the `TintAndShade` fails to work. The brightness of the text in a cell cannot bot be assigned by vba.  Are there any alternative of changing the brightness of the text? Or how can I make `TintAndShade` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are using Excel 2010. And unfortunately it is a bug in Excel 2010. Not sure if it has been rectified in Excel 2013.

Here is an alternative. Create a new workbook and paste this code in a module.

**Logic**: The `.TintAndShade` works for the cell's `.Interior` and hence we will use that instead of `.TintAndShade` for the cell's font.

**Code**:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        .Range("B1:B256").Value = "Blah Blah"
        
        For i = 1 To 256
            .Range("A" & i).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
            .Range("A" & i).Interior.TintAndShade = (i * 2 - 256) / 256
            
            .Range("B" & i).Font.Color = .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**:

When you run this, you will see the change in the Font brightness as shown in the screenshot below. :)

[image]

**Note**:

For a real time scenario, create a temp sheet and in any cell, set it's `.Interior.TintAndShade` and then use that to set the relevant cell's font's brightness and once done, simply delete the temp sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `.color` instead of `.interior.TintSndShade`. Find the color and tint you want from the home tab and font category in excel. Then record a macro of changing the cell's font color to that what you want. Then use the "more color options" and slide the darker/lighter bar up or down very slightly. This will give you `.color` property in your recorded excel macro.

Comment: Good answer.  But if you can make an example macro that would change the font color with a couple of example cells, it will be a great answer.  The question is old, OP already solved his problem; but someone searching for a similar problem may find this question and having a small example in your answer will help him.

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution to this, maybe a little tricky... I created a cell with the required font color but with no text and copy this cell to where I need the color.

```
Dim texxt As String
texxt = Range(N_Range).Value
Range("R3").Copy  'this is my preset cell
Range(N_Range).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = texxt
```